# problem with .load() after several click

Tags: javascript, jquery-selectors, jquery

why after of several click on '#icon a', hang browser will and is run code js bad. 
Everything is bad to when refresh page. i use of chrome, firefox and ...

```
$('#icon a').click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var id = '#' + this.id;
        var title = $(id).attr('title');
        $(".title").toggleClass("suject").html(title);
        var url = $(id).attr('href');
        $('.table_show, #num_count, #select_box, #input_search').fadeOut('slow', function () {
            $('.results').load(url, function(){
                $(this).hide().show();
                $.getScript("http://localhost/Siran-mehdi/files/js/admin.js"); 
            })
            //.hide().show("slow")
        });
    });
```

Comment: `hang browser will and is run code js bad` that is a great impression of yoda :)

Comment: My brain just exploded.  No idea.  I also want to really find out what other browsers he's using!

Answer (score 0):

Clicking several times on the link you run several ajax-requests. That is why it is `hang browser will and is run code js bad` 
Try to disable link after innitial click and enable when ajax-request is finished.

I hope it will help

**UPDATE**
Firs you need to add some class the link. Let it be `clickme`; Than your code will be like this. I have no time to test it, so it is just idea. It should work.

```
$('#icon a.clickme').live('click', function (event) {
        var clickedLink=$(this);
        clickedLink.toggleClass('clickme');  //disabling link
        event.preventDefault();
        var id = '#' + this.id;
        var title = $(id).attr('title');
        $(".title").toggleClass("suject").html(title);
        var url = $(id).attr('href');
        $('.table_show, #num_count, #select_box, #input_search').fadeOut('slow', function () {
            $('.results').load(url, function(){
                //if load function failed 
                //you may enable link there
                $(this).hide().show();
                $.getScript("http://localhost/Siran-mehdi/files/js/admin.js", function(){
                    clickedLink.toggleClass('clickme');  //enabling link 
                }); 
            })
            //.hide().show("slow")
        });
    });
```

Comment: Thank you, how does it do? please give me a example.

Comment: this not worked: my link is this: '<a href="http://localhost/test.php" id="delete_icon"></a>' where put class clickme?

Comment: Change `live('clickme', function (event)`->`live('click', function (event)`

It is stupid typo. Add class to the link you clicking.
`<a href="localhost/test.php"; id="delete_icon" class="clickme"></a>`

Answer (score 0):

From the jQuery documentation (http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/)

> This is a shorthand Ajax function, which is equivalent to:
>
> $.ajax({   url: url,   dataType: "script",   success: success });

This means an asynchronous ajax call is being made every time the link is clicked, and is probably causing problems when clicked again before the ajax call finishes. You could try disabling the link until the ajax request completes.

Comment: means change of .load() to $.ajax()?